# Getting MongoServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to 65.1.249.244:27017 closed error even when i have ip address configured

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, backend, mongodb-atlas

I am getting this error when i am running POST API on MongodB atlas. Although all things are working fine when i am connecting with Compass but whenever i change uri to an atlas one i get this error as below

```
89Error posting work for review: MongoServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to 65.1.249.244:27017 closed
    at EventTarget.<anonymous> (H:\Placement Resources\Projects\nextspark\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:276:34)
    at [nodejs.internal.kHybridDispatch] (node:internal/event_target:741:20)
    at EventTarget.dispatchEvent (node:internal/event_target:683:26)
    at abortSignal (node:internal/abort_controller:368:10)
    at TimeoutController.abort (node:internal/abort_controller:402:5)
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (H:\Placement Resources\Projects\nextspark\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:1011:92)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    servers: Map(3) {
      'ac-d7ocnag-shard-00-01.1hooxsz.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'ac-d7ocnag-shard-00-02.1hooxsz.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'ac-d7ocnag-shard-00-00.1hooxsz.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: 'atlas-149pyq-shard-0',
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined,
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {},
  [cause]: MongoNetworkError: connection <monitor> to 65.1.249.244:27017 closed
      at Connection.onClose (H:\Placement Resources\Projects\nextspark\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:124:28)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (H:\Placement Resources\Projects\nextspark\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:66:46)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:514:28)
      at TCP.<anonymous> (node:net:323:12) {
    [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' },
    [cause]: undefined
  }
}
```

I searched online and found some stackoverflow and mongodb community posts they told me to fix ip address in network access.
I changed it to this but still i am getting that error. Please help it's been a month i procrastinated on this project and still not through it.
[Network Access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSKKZ.png)